# Share variables across stages in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out how to share custom variables across ADO pipelines in my script. Below is my script with 2 stages.

I am setting the `curProjVersion` as an output variable and trying to access it from a different stage. Am I doing it right?

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: VersionCheck
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    displayName: Version Check
    continueOnError: false
    steps:

      - script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=curProjVersion;isOutput=true]1.4.5"
        name: setCurProjVersion
        displayName: "Collect Application Version ID"

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
    curProjVersion1: $[ dependencies.Build.VersionCheck.outputs['setCurProjVersion.curProjVersion'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps: 
      - script: |
          echo $(curProjVersion1)
```

Comment: more detailed explanation with sample source code explained [here](https://rollendxavier.medium.com/sharing-variables-between-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines-59eb8decf3b0)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Updated:**

Share variables across stages feature has been released in [Sprint 168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages) now.

Please use below format to access output variables from previous stage:

```
stageDependencies.{stageName}.{jobName}.outputs['{stepName}.{variableName}']
```

**Original:**

> Share variables across stages in Azure DevOps Pipelines

I'm afraid to say that it does not supported to share the variable which defined in one stage and pass it into another stage.

This is the feature we are plan to add, but until now, it does not supported. You can follow this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743), many people has the same demand with you. You can follow track that.

Until now, we only support set a [multi-job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable), but this only support YAML. For Classic Editor, there's no any plan to add this feature in release.

For work around, you can predefined the variables before the stages. But one important thing is if you change its value in one stage. The new value could not be passed to the next stage. The lifetime of variable with new value only exists in stage.

Comment: It's reported to work now: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743#issuecomment-643469964

Comment: it works for jobs but not for deployment jobs - any chance of looking at it?

Comment: The initially documented syntax DOES NOT work for stage conditions. The correct syntax (for stage conditions) is `stageDependencies.{stageName}.outputs['{jobName}.{stepName}.{variableName}']`. See [github issue on cross-stage variables](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743#issuecomment-643469964) for more info.

Comment: I have multiple templates linked to the main pipeline yml. Each template contains a stage and at least a job. One thing I noticed in this scenario is stage dependencies will only read output variables in previous template

Comment: For conditions see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66119270/5770014)

Comment: major limitation is it forces the hardcode of  stageName, jobName,  stepName which makes it worthless in a pipeline template

Comment: more detailed explanation with sample source code explained [here](https://rollendxavier.medium.com/sharing-variables-between-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines-59eb8decf3b0)

Comment: @scorpio for deployment jobs you have slightly different syntax! You need to add job name again. Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages

Answer (score 27):

What is important to mention `stageDependencies` is not available in `condition` at stage level. It is aviable in jobs, but not in stage directly (at least at the moment).

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to true
      name: DetermineResult
    - script: echo $(DetermineResult.doThing)
      name: echovar
  - job: JA_2
    dependsOn: JA
    condition: eq(dependencies.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes')
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Bar."

#stage B runs if DetermineResult task set doThing variable n stage A
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: JB
    condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') #map doThing and check if true
    variables:
      varFromStageA: $[ stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'] ]
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage B first job"
    - script: echo $(varFromStageA)
```

Comment: This appears to no longer work because the reference should be `$[ stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['JA.DetermineResult.doThing'] ]`

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work passing it as a `parameter` with a template that contains `JB`, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @Roelant please create a new question for this. It would be difficult to reply you in a comment.

Answer (score 18):

Jobs can now access variables from previous stages

Output variables are still produced by steps inside of jobs. Instead of referring to `dependencies.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`, stages refer to `stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#azure-pipelines-1

Answer (score 18):

**This is available as of May 4th 2020**

[Jobs can access output variables from previous stages:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages)

Output variables may now be used across stages in a YAML-based pipeline. This helps you pass useful information, such as a go/no-go decision or the ID of a generated output, from one stage to the next. The result (status) of a previous stage and its jobs is also available.

Output variables are still produced by steps inside of jobs. Instead of referring to `dependencies.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`, stages refer to `stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`.

Note

By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. Therefore, each stage can use output variables from the prior stage. You can alter the dependency graph, which will also alter which output variables are available. For instance, if stage 3 needs a variable from stage 1, it will need to declare an explicit dependency on stage 1.

Comment: the note you copied from the docs helped me. My dependency wasn't working, but I didn't add an explicit dependency on the the prior stage

Comment: The line, "For instance, if stage 3 needs a variable from stage 1, it will need to declare an explicit dependency on stage 1" is exactly what I was missing. Read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#:~:text=Output%20variables%20are%20only%20available%20in%20the%20next%20downstream%20stage.%20If%20multiple%20stages%20consume%20the%20same%20output%20variable%2C%20use%20the%20dependsOn%20condition.)

Answer (score 8):

**For stage conditions** on Azure DevOps Version Dev17.M153.5 with Agent Version 2.153.1 the following works:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to 'Yes'
      name: DetermineResult

#stage B runs if DetermineResult task set doThing variable on stage A
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['JA.DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes')
  jobs:
  - job: JB
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage B first job"
```

**Note**: The layout of properties is different on stage compared to job:

`dependencies.{stage name}.outputs['{job name}.{script name}.{variable name}']`

**Note**: The expression with 'stageDependencies' failed with the following error message:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: 'stageDependencies'. Located at position XX within expression: and(always(), eq(stageDependencies.A.outputs['JA.DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes')). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

**Bonus**:

See the following documentation on how to access the *status of the dependent stages*: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions)

**Corresponding documentations**:

- [Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)
- [Stage to stage dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies)

> To use the output from a different stage, you must use the syntax depending on whether you're at the stage or job level:
>
> - At the stage level, the format for referencing variables from a different stage is `dependencies.STAGE.outputs['JOB.TASK.VARIABLE']`. You can use these variables in conditions.
> - At the job level, the format for referencing variables from a different stage is `stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']`
>
> *Note*: By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. If you need to refer to a stage that isn't immediately prior to the current one, you can override this automatic default by adding a `dependsOn` section to the stage.

Comment: The above description still works on Azure DevOps Server Version 2020 Update 1.1 with Agent Version 2.191.1 (Windows and Linux agents as well)

Comment: Worked fine for me, Azure DevOps (cloud) / self-hosted Linux agents. 
Caution!!! As written in this answer, make sure to use `name: DetermineResult` and not `displayName: DetermineResult`. Just wasted 30 minutes until I figured out...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you need stageDependencies like below:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: VersionCheck
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    displayName: Version Check
    continueOnError: false
    steps:

      - script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=curProjVersion;isOutput=true]1.4.5"
        name: setCurProjVersion
        displayName: "Collect Application Version ID"

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
    curProjVersion1: $[ stageDependencies.Build.VersionCheck.outputs['setCurProjVersion.curProjVersion'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps: 
      - script: |
          echo $(curProjVersion1)
```

Note that I have changed

```
$[ dependencies.Build.VersionCheck.outputs['setCurProjVersion.curProjVersion'] ]
```

TO

```
$[ stageDependencies.Build.VersionCheck.outputs['setCurProjVersion.curProjVersion'] ]
```

source: https://jimferrari.com/2023/01/05/pass-variables-across-jobs-and-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines/

Comment: how do i do it if insted of - job: VersionCheck i have - template: jobs/checkprojectype.yaml@devops

Comment: I assume you are trying to pass job to job in the same stage? Can you send me a full code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

As an update for anyone seeing this question, it seems passing variables between stages [has been implemented and should be released in the next couple of weeks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743#issuecomment-614654346).

Comment: "Links are fantastic, but they should never be the [only piece of information in your answer." https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Answer (score 0):

**important notice** to the solution:

it is only suitable for **1** directly following stage.

assuming you have:

- stageA - sets variable X
- stageB - consumes variable X over stageDependencies - works
- stageC - can't consume variable X unless you specify the `dependsOn` stageA **and** stageB.

this is a gotcha i faced recently, the value of variable X consumed by stageC was empty. when you specify `dependsOn`, you can't just add stageA, it then becomes a parallel stage (what?), so you need to add **both** stageA and stageB. but such pipeline looks silly.

so i suggest to use artifacts instead. looks like a more robust solution for me.

Comment: Helpful . I stumbled on this and tried all possible ways. Your finding worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a global variable and use a Powershell to assign the value of the stage variable to the global variable.

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=globalVar;]$stageVar")
```

Global variables can either be defined in the yaml itself or in variable groups. 
Initialise the var with an empty value.

E.g. yaml

```
  variables:
    globalVar: ''
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try this out.

Comment: Hey @zooes did that end up working out for you? I found this discussion on GitHub where it seems like the only way is to save it to AKV, or use a DB/file somewhere
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743

Comment: @bla9x - No, it didnt work, because looks like MS-ADO doesnt let you share vars across stages. And you are right, the only way to share it, is either AKV/DB/File.

Comment: It creates snapshot for each job. So `globalVar` in one stage is sth different than `globalvar` in a different job. So this mechanism you can use to pass the same value across all jobs in all stages, but not to pass value from one to another. For that purpose you should use `output variable` which are available to share values across stages (at the moment of writing this comment).

Answer (score -3):

You can define the variables just after you define the trigger and before you define the stages

```
trigger:
- master
  variables:
    VarA: aaaaa
    VarB: bbbbb
stages:
- stage: Build  
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
```

Comment: Looking at the docs the var declaration goes at the root level, at the top of the file. When I add it to the trigger my vscode extensions throws an error `Unexpected property variables`