# Can you use build tags in conditions statements in multi-stage devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

Is it possible to use the build tags set on a multi-stage pipeline build, in the condition section of a later stage?

```
    ##### task in build stage #####
    - task: YodLabs.VariableTasks.AddTag.AddTag@0
      displayName: Adding environment tag to build
      inputs:
        tags: |
          deploy
          $(DEPLOY_ENV)
```

```
  #### some later stage ####
  - stage: deploy
    displayName: deploy
    condition: |
      and(
        succeeded(),
        #Is there something I can put here to condition on tags
      )
    jobs:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know this is not possible with YAML yet, because there is no easy way to get tags availabe in YAML. What you can try is `output variable`

```
jobs:
- job: Foo
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "This is job Foo."
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to true
    name: DetermineResult
- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  condition: eq(dependencies.Foo.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') #map doThing and check if true
  steps:
  - script: echo "Job Foo ran and doThing is true."
```

You can also try with workaraund which is in this case:

1. Fetch tags using REST API in powershell script `PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/tags/{tag}?api-version=5.1`
2. Then assign your tags to output variables using logging commands
3. And finally use output variable in condition

**EDIT**

So it looks that this is not possible at the moment but should be available soon. Please check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743).

> Output variables may now be used across stages in a YAML-based
>   pipeline. This helps you pass useful information, such as a go/no-go
>   decision or the ID of a generated output, from one stage to the next.
>   The result (status) of a previous stage and its jobs is also
>   available.
>
> Output variables are still produced by steps inside of jobs. Instead
>   of referring to `dependencies.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`,
>   stages refer to
>   `stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`.
>   Note: by default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just
>   before it in the YAML file. Therefore, each stage can use output
>   variables from the prior stage. You can alter the dependency graph,
>   which will also alter which output variables are available. For
>   instance, if stage 3 needs a variable from stage 1, it will need to
>   declare an explicit dependency on stage 1.

I tried it now:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to true
      name: DetermineResult

# stage B runs if A fails
- stage: B
  condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') #map doThing and check if true
  jobs:
  - job: JB
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage B first job"
```

but I got this error:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized
>   value: 'stageDependencies'. Located at position 4 within expression:
>   eq(stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes').
>   For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

However, this feature can be soon with us!

Comment: Unfortunately output variables at the job level won't be available across stages. So with either of those options my stage would need an initial job first to get the values before I can add conditions. I have something similar to this working now; but using a bash script that's stored in the build output. What I'm wanting to do is skip an entire stage without having to run any jobs on it

Comment: Excellent find on the edit. I'll keep an eye on the release notes for the feature implementation.

Comment: About the "feature can be soon with us": I believe it is there by now. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485621/share-variables-across-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines