# Incrementally update environment variable (object) in different Azure pipelines powershell tasks

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

On a pipeline, I have two powershell tasks that read variables from different files, and I want to copy those variables into the same environment variable. This design is being used across multiple pipelines, and I can't change it.

The following code in the powershell script is used for that effect, which copies the variables read from the file, contained in the `fileParameters` object, into the `envParameters` object:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=envParameters;]$($fileParameters)"
```

The above would work well if I would be executing the task once. But since the task is executed twice, the second execution deletes all the `envParameters` properties read in the first script execution. Is there a way to update `envParameters` without deleting the already existing properties?

Comment: Check this answer to see if it helps you, seems like if you can change your jobs a bit, you can do this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654446/1238413

Comment: If you can't change jobs at that level, you can use your same approach reading from a file, just resaving the env values as a variable at the end of each step.

Comment: @FoxDeploy your first solution implies changes in many places. Regarding the second, the `fileParameters` contains already such values. Can you explain a little bit better your idea?