# Share variables across steps in different stages in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out how to share custom variables across steps in different stages in my pipeline. I have three pipelines, where the first looks for changes to the repo to find any changes and set variables that are then consumed in a step in the other stages. I have tried both the `dependencies.Stage.outputs['Job.step.variable']` and `stageDependencies.Stage.Job.outputs['step.variable']` but both give me errors that `dependencies` and `stageDependencies` are unrecognized values. I assume that this is because these are stage and job-level variables and not accessible in the steps inside of a job. How would I be able to access these variables?

I have multiple steps in the child stage and job that should run whether or not the variables are set, which makes it so that I can't just make a stage or job condition.

```
stages:
  - stage: BuildAndUnit
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      steps:
      - task: touchify.vsts-changed-files.vsts-changed-files.ChangedFiles@1
        displayName: 'Detect Changes'
        inputs:
          rules: |
            [RunBackendTests]
            !+(WebUi|Web2)/**
            [RunNgWebAppTests]
            Web2/*
            Web2/!(administration)/**
            [RunNgWebAdminTests]
            Web2/package.json
            Web2/package-lock.json
            Web2/administration/**
  - stage: CoreTests
    displayName: 'Core Tests'
    dependsOn: BuildAndUnit
    jobs:
    - job: CoreTest
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Ng WebApp Unit Test'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          customCommand: ''
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.BuildAndUnit.Build.outputs['ChangedFiles.runngwebapptests'], 'true'))
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Run Ng WebAdmin Unit Tests'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          customCommand: ''
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.BuildAndUnit.Build.outputs['stageDependencies.BuildAndUnit.Build.outputs['ChangedFiles.runngwebadmintests'], 'true'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485621/share-variables-across-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines

Answer (score 3):

I finally found it! Here it is for someone in the future looking for similar things, just import the variables at the job level.

```
stages:
  - stage: BuildAndUnit
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      steps:
      - task: touchify.vsts-changed-files.vsts-changed-files.ChangedFiles@1
        displayName: 'Detect Changes'
        inputs:
          rules: |
            [RunBackendTests]
            !+(WebUi|Web2)/**
            [RunNgWebAppTests]
            Web2/*
            Web2/!(administration)/**
            [RunNgWebAdminTests]
            Web2/package.json
            Web2/package-lock.json
            Web2/administration/**
  - stage: CoreTests
    displayName: 'Core Tests'
    dependsOn: BuildAndUnit
    jobs:
    - job: CoreTest
      variables:
        runngwebapptests: $[ stageDependencies.BuildAndUnit.Build.outputs['ChangedFiles.runngwebapptests'] ]
        runngwebadmintests: $[ stageDependencies.BuildAndUnit.Build.outputs['ChangedFiles.runngwebadmintests'] ]
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Ng WebApp Unit Test'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          customCommand: ''
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['runngwebapptests'], 'true'))
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Run Ng WebAdmin Unit Tests'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          customCommand: ''
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['runngwebadmintests'], 'true'))
```

Comment: Nice answer/solution. You can accept your own answer!