# how to pass variables between stages with templates in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im trying to pass variables between stages with jobs that is using templates in azure pipeline , tried a lot of methods but still did not managed to achieve it.

i have job that is checking something and create vso task.variable and this variables i want to pass to next stage

**azure-pipelines.yaml**

```
stages:

  - stage: CheckProjectType
    displayName: Check Project Type
    jobs:            
      - template: jobs/checkprojectype.yaml@devops

  - stage: PrintProjectType
    dependsOn: CheckProjectType
    displayName: Print Project Type
    jobs: 
      - template: jobs/buildproject.yaml@devops
        parameters:
          outputval: $[ stagedependencies.CheckProjectType.outputs['SetValueStep.projecttype'] ]
```

**checkprojectype.yaml**

```
jobs:
- job: CheckProjectType
  displayName: Check Project Type
  steps:
  - bash: |
      if [ -f *.xml ]; then
        echo "JAVA"
      elif [ -f *.json ]; then
        echo "json file found , Nodejs Project Will Be Built"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projecttype;]nodejs"
      elif [ -f *.py ]; then
        echo "Python"
      else
        echo "Not Found"
      fi
    name: itay
    displayName: Checking Current Location
```

**buildproject.yaml**

```
jobs:
- job: BuildProject
  variables:
  - name: myvar123
    value: ${{ parameters.outputval }}
  steps:
  - bash: echo $(myvar123)
```

and i expect to get nodejs , but I Dont get anything , the echo is empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share variables across stages in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485621/share-variables-across-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines)

Comment: @TomW Unfortunately no,already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a *task variable* in future stages it needs an additional `isOutput=true` property as mentioned in the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages)

**checkprojectype.yml**

```
jobs:
- job: CheckProjectType
  displayName: Check Project Type
  steps:
  - bash: |
      if [ -f *.xml ]; then
        echo "JAVA"
      elif [ -f *.json ]; then
        echo "json file found , Nodejs Project Will Be Built"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projecttype;isOutput=true]nodejs"
      elif [ -f *.py ]; then
        echo "Python"
      else
        echo "Not Found"
      fi
    name: itay
    displayName: Checking Current Location
```

Also double-check @tom-w remark and, as your code example does not seem to fit the reference there.

In the example:

```
outputval: $[ stagedependencies.CheckProjectType.outputs['SetValueStep.projecttype'] ]
```

Should be:

```
outputval: $[ stagedependencies.CheckProjectType.CheckProjectType.outputs['itay.projecttype'] ]
```